# Performing a certain operation on arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays `I` and `X`. I want to perform an operation which basically takes the indices from `I` and uses values from `X`. For example, `I[0]=[0,1]`, I want to calculate `X[0]` and `X[1]` followed by `X[0]-X[1]` and append to a new array `T`. Similarly, for `I[1]=[1,2]`, I want to calculate `X[1]` and `X[2]` followed by `X[1]-X[2]` and append to `T`. The expected output is presented.

```
import numpy as np
I=np.array([[0,1],[1,2]])
X=np.array([10,5,3])
```

The expected output is

```
T=array([[X[0]-X[1]],[X[1]-X[2]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic approach is using nested indices together with the `np.append()` function.

It works like below:

```
T = np.append(X[I[0][0]] - X[I[0][1]], X[I[1][0]] - X[I[1][1]])
```

Where, `X[I[0][0]]` means to extract the value of `I[0][0]` and use that as the index we want for the array X.

You can also implement a loop to do that:

```
T = np.array([], dtype="int64")
for i in range(I.shape[0]):
    for j in range(I.shape[1]-1):
        T = np.append(T, X[I[i][j]] - X[I[i][j+1]])
```

If you find this answer helpful, please accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: How will the answer change if ```X=np.array([[10,5,3]])``` instead of ```X=np.array([10,5,3])```?

Comment: If so, you need to change the last line of the loop to `T = np.append(T, X[0, I[i][j]] - X[0, I[i][j+1]])`

Comment: For large arrays, using for loops like this is going to be much slower than using vectorized operations like what's shown in my answer --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/74761269/1316276.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing). For large arrays, using for loops like in the currently accepted answer is going to be much slower than using vectorized operations.

```
import numpy as np

I = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 2]])
X = np.array([10, 5, 3])
T = X[I[:, 0:1]] - X[I[:, 1:2]]
```